# Is my kernel version OK or I have to update it?

Tags: 12.04, kernel

I'm using Ubuntu Precise :

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS"
```

but my kernel version is:

```
$ uname -r 
3.0.0-12-generic
```

Is this configuration fine or I have to update my kernel to newer version ?
If yes, how can I do that ?

`apt-cache search linux-image-3` returns

```
linux-image-3.2.0-23-generic - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.2.0-23-virtual - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 Virtual Guests
linux-image-3.2.0-23-generic-pae - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.2.0-23-lowlatency - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on x86/x86_64
linux-image-3.2.0-23-lowlatency-pae - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on x86
linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.2.0-24-virtual - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 Virtual Guests
linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic-pae - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic-pae - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.2.0-25-virtual - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 Virtual Guests
linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic-pae - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.2.0-26-virtual - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 Virtual Guests
linux-image-3.2.0-27-generic - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.2.0-27-generic-pae - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.2.0-27-virtual - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 Virtual Guests
linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic-pae - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.2.0-29-virtual - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 Virtual Guests
linux-image-3.2.0-30-generic - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.2.0-30-generic-pae - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.2.0-30-virtual - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 Virtual Guests
linux-image-3.2.0-31-generic - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.2.0-31-generic-pae - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.2.0-31-virtual - Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 Virtual Guests
linux-image-3.5.0-15-generic - Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.5.0-13-generic - Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.0.0-12-generic - Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0 on x86/x86_64
```

the   `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` command returns (I removed commented lines)

```
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main #Third party developers repository
```

and `dpkg -l | grep "linux\-[a-z]*\-"` returns

```
ii  linux-headers-2.6.38-10                                     2.6.38-10.46                                                            Header files related to Linux kernel version 2.6.38
ii  linux-headers-2.6.38-10-generic                             2.6.38-10.46                                                            Linux kernel headers for version 2.6.38 on x86/x86_64
ii  linux-headers-2.6.38-11                                     2.6.38-11.50                                                            Header files related to Linux kernel version 2.6.38
ii  linux-headers-2.6.38-11-generic                             2.6.38-11.50                                                            Linux kernel headers for version 2.6.38 on x86/x86_64
ii  linux-headers-3.0.0-12                                      3.0.0-12.20                                                             Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.0.0
ii  linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic                              3.0.0-12.20                                                             Linux kernel headers for version 3.0.0 on x86/x86_64
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-24                                      3.2.0-24.39                                                             Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.2.0
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-24-generic                              3.2.0-24.39                                                             Linux kernel headers for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-24-generic-pae                          3.2.0-24.39                                                             Linux kernel headers for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-25                                      3.2.0-25.40                                                             Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.2.0
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic                              3.2.0-25.40                                                             Linux kernel headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic-pae                          3.2.0-25.40                                                             Linux kernel headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-26                                      3.2.0-26.41                                                             Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.2.0
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic                              3.2.0-26.41                                                             Linux kernel headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic-pae                          3.2.0-26.41                                                             Linux kernel headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-27                                      3.2.0-27.43                                                             Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.2.0
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-27-generic                              3.2.0-27.43                                                             Linux kernel headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-27-generic-pae                          3.2.0-27.43                                                             Linux kernel headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-29                                      3.2.0-29.46                                                             Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.2.0
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic                              3.2.0-29.46                                                             Linux kernel headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic-pae                          3.2.0-29.46                                                             Linux kernel headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-30                                      3.2.0-30.48                                                             Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.2.0
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-30-generic                              3.2.0-30.48                                                             Linux kernel headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-30-generic-pae                          3.2.0-30.48                                                             Linux kernel headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.5.0-13                                      3.5.0-13.13                                                             Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.5.0
ii  linux-headers-3.5.0-13-generic                              3.5.0-13.13                                                             Linux kernel headers for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.5.0-15                                      3.5.0-15.22                                                             Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.5.0
ii  linux-headers-3.5.0-15-generic                              3.5.0-15.22                                                             Linux kernel headers for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                                       3.5.0.15.15                                                             Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-headers-generic-pae                                   3.5.0.15.15                                                             Transitional package
rc  linux-image-2.6.28-11-generic                               2.6.28-11.42                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.28 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.28-15-generic                               2.6.28-15.52                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.28 on x86/x86_64
ii  linux-image-2.6.28-16-generic                               2.6.28-16.55                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.28 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.31-14-generic                               2.6.31-14.48                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.31 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.31-15-generic                               2.6.31-15.50                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.31 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.31-16-generic                               2.6.31-16.53                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.31 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.31-17-generic                               2.6.31-17.54                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.31 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.31-19-generic                               2.6.31-19.56                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.31 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.31-20-generic                               2.6.31-20.58                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.31 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.31-21-generic                               2.6.31-21.59                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.31 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.32-21-generic                               2.6.32-21.32                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.32-22-generic                               2.6.32-22.36                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.32-23-generic                               2.6.32-23.37                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.32-24-generic                               2.6.32-24.43                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.32-25-generic                               2.6.32-25.45                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.32-26-generic                               2.6.32-26.48                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.32-27-generic                               2.6.32-27.49                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.32-28-generic                               2.6.32-28.55                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.32-29-generic                               2.6.32-29.58                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.32-30-generic                               2.6.32-30.59                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86/x86_64
ii  linux-image-2.6.32-31-generic                               2.6.32-31.61                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-2.6.35-28-generic                               2.6.35-28.50                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.35 on x86/x86_64
ii  linux-image-2.6.38-10-generic                               2.6.38-10.46                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.38 on x86/x86_64
ii  linux-image-2.6.38-11-generic                               2.6.38-11.50                                                            Linux kernel image for version 2.6.38 on x86/x86_64
ii  linux-image-2.6.38-8-generic                                2.6.38-8.42                                                             Linux kernel image for version 2.6.38 on x86/x86_64
ii  linux-image-3.0.0-12-generic                                3.0.0-12.20                                                             Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-3.0.0-13-generic                                3.0.0-13.22                                                             Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-3.0.0-14-generic                                3.0.0-14.23                                                             Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-3.0.0-15-generic                                3.0.0-15.26                                                             Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-3.0.0-16-generic                                3.0.0-16.29                                                             Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-image-3.0.0-17-generic                                3.0.0-17.30                                                             Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0 on x86/x86_64
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic                                3.2.0-24.39                                                             Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic                                3.2.0-25.40                                                             Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic                                3.2.0-26.41                                                             Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-27-generic                                3.2.0-27.43                                                             Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic                                3.2.0-29.46                                                             Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-30-generic                                3.2.0-30.48                                                             Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-13-generic                                3.5.0-13.13                                                             Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-15-generic                                3.5.0-15.22                                                             Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.5.0-13-generic                          3.5.0-13.13                                                             Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.5.0-15-generic                          3.5.0-15.22                                                             Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                         3.5.0.15.15                                                             Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-libc-dev                                              3.5.0-15.22                                                             Linux Kernel Headers for development
rc  linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-11-generic                  2.6.28-11.15                                                            Non-free Linux kernel modules for version 2.6.28 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-15-generic                  2.6.28-15.20                                                            Non-free Linux kernel modules for version 2.6.28 on x86/x86_64
rc  linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-16-generic                  2.6.28-16.21                                                            Non-free Linux kernel modules for version 2.6.28 on x86/x86_64
ii  linux-sound-base                                            1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu1                                                    base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
```

Comment: Open the Update Manager, it's always better to have software updated, *anywhere* *any software*.

Comment: My problem isn't with ubuntu version. It is with the kernel version displayed when I do `uname -r` it returns 
3.0.0-12-generic and precise up-to-date is running

Comment: Could you please show the output from the following commands, `apt-cache search linux-image-3`, `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `dpkg -l | grep "linux\-[a-z]*\-"`. Edit your question with this additional informations.

Comment: Are you using GRUB2 (v 1.99) or the old GRUB? It looks like GRUB is not updating.

Comment: I don't know. How can I find the GRUB version ?

Comment: I find it `/usr/sbin/grub --version`
grub (GNU GRUB 0.97)
So I have to updgrade my GRUB ?

Comment: You have the old grub. Updating grub will solve the problem as the new grub is better at keeping track of kernels and other OSs in the hard drives. Follow this how to: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Upgrading

Comment: Done. I updated the GRUB and the kernel. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the old grub. Updating grub will solve the problem as the new grub is better at keeping track of kernels and other OSs in the hard drives.

Follow this how to: http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Upgrading

Thanks to  [user68186](https://askubuntu.com/users/68186/user68186)

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge the latest version available in the repository is `3.2.0-31-generic`. This means your kernel is indeed fairly outdated. Best practice is to always keep your computer as up to date as possible and Ubuntu is no exception.

You can update the kernel on a desktop system by using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
```

If you also want to update all other software this can be done by issuing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Be warned that these commands do require `sudo` (admin) privileges and you have to reboot afterwards.

Simpler is to use the update manager to check for updates and install them:

[image: Updating through the UI 2]

Comment: Or use the Update Manager to Update, commands are handy when the GUI fails to do anything.

Comment: When I do `sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic` I got `linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
linux-image-generic is already the newest version.
linux-generic is already the newest version.` and my kernel version is unchanged : `uname -r` 
3.0.0-12-generic

Answer (score 0):

In [my case](https://askubuntu.com/q/590572/187984) I had to [upgrade the Hardware Enablement Stack HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), in order to receive the latest kernel.