# Why is my kernel not upgraded to the latest version?

Tags: 12.04, server, apt, upgrade, kernel

My server runs Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS. I try to keep it up to date as possible by doing 
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` regularly. So far I was assuming that this would update the kernel as well. Today I noticed however that I am running a totally outdated kernel (`uname-r` gives 3.2.0-77-generic).

Doing `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` didn't fix this. Then I tried `sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic` - also with no success...

Why am I not receiving the latest kernels and how can I fix this?

Comment: You need to upgrade the Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE). Right now I imagine the `-utopic` HWE packages should be present.

Comment: @muru Thanks. I will look into the HWE. Why isn't that happening automatically?

Comment: Perhaps a kernel+driver upgrade is considered important enough that the user should do it manually. Along with showing the number of packages that can be upgraded as part of the MOTD, you are also told when the your HWE is out-of-date, and the commands to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks @muru. As explained [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), I did `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-trusty` (note **trusty**) and now I am on 3.13.0-46. 

I am not sure if this question is a duplicate, since mine is more specific on keeping the kernel up-to-date. So if you would like to provide an answer you will have my upvote ;)